# How to subscribe to broadcast address in node.js (255.255.255.255)

Tags: javascript, node.js, udp, multicast

I cannot listen to messages being broadcast on `255.255.255.255`. The [ArtNet protocol docs](https://art-net.org.uk/general-network-terminology-2/casting/) say that ArtNet controllers broadcast onto `255.255.255.255` on port 6454 (see also [here](https://art-net.org.uk/structure/discovery-packets/).

When I try to listen to `255.255.255.255` using node.js's `dgram` module, I get an "EINVAL" errror, because `255.255.255.255` is an invalid address.

I've tried subscribing to `192.255.255.255`, `192.168.255.255`, and `192.168.10.255` (instead of `255.255.255.255`). None of these work either. Tested on Windows and Ubuntu.

```
const dgram = require('dgram');

const sock = dgram.createSocket('udp4', (msg, peer) => {
  console.log(msg, peer);
});

sock.bind(6454, () => {
  sock.addMembership('255.255.255.255');
});
```

Stacktrace:

```
dgram.js:581
    throw errnoException(err, 'addMembership');
    ^

Error: addMembership EINVAL
    at Socket.addMembership (dgram.js:581:11)
    at Socket.sock.bind (/home/kyle/temptest/listen3.js:15:8)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at startListening (dgram.js:128:10)
    at state.handle.lookup (dgram.js:249:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:834:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`socket.addMembership()` is used to enroll a socket as a destination for **multicast** traffic.  Your use case here is **broadcast**, not multicast, so don't try to use `addMembership()` at all.

You shouldn't need to do anything special to receive broadcast traffic.  Just `bind()` your socket to the appropriate port (in this case 6454) as you are already doing, and then your socket's message-event callback should fire whenever a broadcast to that port is received.

If you want to write a test program to exercise your listener by sending broadcast traffic to port 6454 then that test program will need to call `setBroadcast()` on its dgram socket before trying to `send()` to port 6454 at the `255.255.255.255` broadcast address.

Answer (score 0):

`Error: addMembership EINVAL
    at Socket.addMembership (dgram.js:581:11)
    ...`

EINVAL - means Error: Invalid Value.
You cannot bind socket to any broadcast address as stated in number of RFCs.